# Проверка правильности ввода

Tags: python, циклы

Я хотел сделать так, чтобы зациклилось предложение ввести номер месяца, пока он не будет 1 или 2 или 3 ... или 12
Но цикл просто не работает.
Что я делаю не так?

Вот весь код

```
while True:
num = int(input("Введите номер месяца = "))
if num == 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:
    break
```

А это результат:
[image: Результат]

Comment: `if 1 <= num <= 12` или `if num in range(1, 13)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Введите номер месяца = "))
    if (num == 1 or 
        num == 2 or 
        num == 3 or 
        num == 4 or 
        num == 5 or 
        num == 6 or 
        num == 7 or 
        num == 8 or 
        num == 9 or 
        num == 10 or 
        num == 11 or 
        num == 12):
        break
print('break 1 is working')

# лучше так
template = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
while True:
    num = int(input("Введите номер месяца = "))
    if num in template:
        break
print('break 2 is working')
```